# Error "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Int64?)'" with nil-coalescing operator

Tags: swift, int64

I am getting an error "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Int64?)'" with nil-coalescing operator.

There are similar questions on stack**overflow**, but they did not give me the solution I need.

My code with errors in comments:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "countCell", for: indexPath)
cell.textLabel?.text = String(detailItem?.count) ?? "1" // Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Int64?)'

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "countCell", for: indexPath)
cell.textLabel?.text = String(Int(detailItem?.count)) ?? "1" // Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(Int64?)'

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "countCell", for: indexPath)
cell.textLabel?.text = String(Int(detailItem!.count)) ?? "1" // Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(Int64?)'

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "countCell", for: indexPath)
cell.textLabel?.text = String(detailItem?.count ?? "1") // Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int64'
```

Comment: What about `let string = String(intValue)` – as for other integer and floating point types?

Comment: I tried let string = String(int64Value), and I get an error.

Comment: That would have been useful information in the question, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: What is the value of `int64Value`?

Comment: @MartinR I was in the process of adding that information. I posted and then edited. I didn't expect to receive answers so quickly.

Comment: @PGDev int64Value = 1.

Comment: Try the code that I've added in the answer. Also, post the error that you're getting.

Comment: @PGDev Ok. I'm working on it. Playground is really slow. I'm trying it on Playground.

Comment: What does `print(type(of: int64Value))` print?

Comment: `'(Int64?)'` in the error message indicates that `detailItem?.count` is an *optional* integer, you have to unwrap it first.

Comment: Updated the answer as per your code. Try that.

Comment: I'm not using Playground anymore, but it's my Mac mini that is slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do,

```
let int64Value: Int64 = 123
let str = String(int64Value)
```

**Edit:**

Since `detailItem?.count` is `optional`, you need to *unwrap* it before passing it to the `String` *initializer*. You can use ***nil coalescing operator*** to unwrap and provide a default value, i.e.

```
cell.textLabel?.text = String(detailItem?.count ?? 1)
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried it.

Comment: Add the code that doesn't work.

Comment: Updated the code with the relevant solution.

Comment: It looks like that works. The error message disappeared. Xcode is still building. My Mac mini is really slow right now.

Comment: Great, Do accept if the answer worked. Happy coding..

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
let tmp = Int64(10)
print(String(tmp))
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I've tried it.

Comment: its working on my playground